# grails searchable with query builder can't find entity

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-searchable, searchable-plugin

Using searchable plugin with grails 2.3.4 and a postgreSql datasource.
The plugin can't render the result when i build a query with a closure:

1) Having a domain Test:

```
import org.compass.annotations.*

class Test implements Serializable {
    static searchable = true

    @SearchableProperty
    Currency currency

    @SearchableProperty
    String type
```

2) A service which wires searchableService:

```
class SearchService {

    def searchableService

    def mysearch() {
       def results = Test.search{
           must(term('type', 'OFFICES'))
           term('currency', 'USD')
       }
       return results
    }
```

In spite of the well recorded Test entity with string values 'OFFICES' and 'USD' for type and currency properties, the query builder can't find any result...

Comment: ...because Currency is not of type String as specified in your criteria?

Comment: Currency is an enum in the domain, but a character var in database. I thought the same at first glance, but same result with type only which is defined as a String..

Comment: for info, using must(queryString("OFFICES")) returns the target entity... but i need to use a complex query so i wish i could put terms in a closure.

Comment: transforming the search in: "must(term('type',values['type'].toLowerCase()))" did the job, but it's odd that compass can't represent the string as it's recorded in db